# Return only unique records in this ActiveRecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a mildly-complex ActiveRecord query in Rails 3.2 / Postgres that returns documents that are *related* and *most relevant* to *all documents* a user has favorited in the past.

**The problem is that despite specifying `uniq` my query *does not* return distinct document records:**

```
 Document.joins("INNER JOIN related_documents ON 
                 documents.docid = related_documents.docid_id")
         .select("documents.*, related_documents.relevance_score")
         .where("related_documents.document_id IN (?)",    
                  some_user.favorited_documents)
         .order("related_documents.relevance_score DESC")
         .uniq
         .limit(10)
```

I use a `RelatedDocument` join table, ranking each relation by a `related_document.relevance_score` which I use to order the query result before sampling the top 10. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014637/activerecord-query-to-return-related-documents-using-relateddocuments-join-table) for schema description.)

The problem is that because I `select("documents.*, related_documents.relevance_score")`, the same document record returned multiple times with different `relevance_scores` are considered unique results. (i.e. if the document is a related_document for multiple favorited-documents.)

**How do I return unique `Documents` regardless of the `related_document.relevance_score`?**

I have tried splitting the `select` into two seperate selects, and changing the position of `uniq` in the query with no success.

Unfortunately I must `select("related_documents.relevance_score")` so as to order the results by this field.

Thanks!

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Thanks to *Jethroo* below, `GROUP BY` is the needed addition, giving me the follow working query:

```
 Document.joins("INNER JOIN related_documents ON 
                 documents.docid = related_documents.docid_id")
         .select("documents.*, max(related_documents.relevance_score)")
         .where("related_documents.document_id IN (?)",    
                  some_user.favorited_documents)
         .order("related_documents.relevance_score DESC")
         .group("documents.id")
         .uniq
         .limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to group it by `documents.docid` see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group?

Comment: Thanks jethroo, that lead me to the correct solution. I did however need to change some other parts of the query so as to be able to group by all selected columns. I've added the working query as an update to the question.